# How to set cascade to update object

Tags: hibernate, cascade

I have a Student and a School table. When I try to save a School, hibernate also saves Student objects(I am using CascadeType.ALL). What I want to do is; search for Student table and if there is a student with same name(column) then don't save a new Student object. Just save School object and give a reference to this student object. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is your business logic. I suggest to search and set the existing student to new school object. then it will not create new one.Hibernate needs Id to be set in relation, if we dont want it to create new object in cascading.